# Jenkins pipeline debugging

Tags: debugging, jenkins-pipeline, git-push

by running this stage of pipeline the buils got sucess but it did not push (git push does not perform its function).hoe can I solve this issue
stage('Git Push') {
when { branch 'DEVOPS-2872'}
`your text`     steps {
`your text`        // Push changes
`your text`       pwsh(script: "git status")
`your text`      pwsh(script: "git diff")
`your text`     pwsh(script: "git push -f origin       ``` your text``HEAD:refs/heads/${getCurrentBranchName()}") ``` your text`  }
}

some modification in pipeline so that git push works properly